# Dynamic content in _layoutPage.cshtml without controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are trying to Dynamical fetch the list of categories in the template header. 
eg "Shorts, Jeans, Trousers etc." Should appear under category list menu dropdown.

As we know this,layout page  will be global to all the controllers.so which is the best possible way to accomplish this without using any controllers,as we know that layout page is not called by any controller and is just defined
in the view page.

Comment: Is this list static? Is it stored in the database? Does it have a large number of elements?

Comment: It is dynamic and list will keep increasing in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically fetch list on Layout page by making a Ajax request to controller action and return json from there and show on your layout page or you can make a partial view and render the partial view inside layout page with the help of Html helpers like `@Html.RenderAction()` or `@Html.RenderPartial()`

Answer (score 0):

Although the `_Layout.cshtml` (and any other layout/master page, for that matter) is loaded automatically by the MVC framework, it doesn't mean that it cannot use `ViewBag`. I would recommend creating a `BaseController`, that all of your controllers would extend. You could add the list of categories to the `ViewBag` inside the `BaseController`, which will make it available in your layout page.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = GetAllCategories();
    }

}
```

I know that you specified that you don't want a "controller solution", but I believe that you didn't know that this was actually possible. In fact, having a base controller can bring a lot of functionality to your project. Everything that needs to be reused by your controllers can be set inside the `BaseController`: data, methods, controller filters, etc.

The `ViewBag` method is already used in the framework. I don't remember how the MVC5 template looks like, but if you look at the MVC4 template, you'll see that the `_Layout.cshtml` page uses the `ViewBag` to set the title of the current page: `<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>`.

Comment: Just a query,do we have to use viewmodel class.I heard that data can be passed directly from model to view.

Comment: @user3818870 I don't know what you mean by _"data can be passed directly from model to view"_, but it's up to you if you want to create a view model. The advantage of creating a view model is that you can cast the data you pass trough the `ViewBag` and have a strongly typed object. If you have just a list of strings, for example, you don't need a custom model; you can just do this in the layout page: `List<string> cotegories = ViewBag.Categories as List<string>;`.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to go with @Html.RenderAction(). 
Reasons:
     1. Best Performance
     2. You can cache data of this action.
     3. Easy to maintain.